# EmailMessage Trigger causes missing EmailStatus records

Tags: apex, after-trigger, emailmessage

An apparent problem we have found using an Apex Trigger on the standard 'EmailMessage' object is as follows:

The trigger handles the 'after insert' event and when an email is sent (e.g. from an Apex Class which uses the Messaging.sendEmail() method) it determines the values for certain custom fields on the EmailMessage object and executes a DML update on the EmailMessage record.

This works successfully, emails are successfully received, passes all tests, etc.

The problem seems to be that when this Trigger is active no 'EmailStatus' records are created for the Tasks records associated with the emails. The consquence of this is that Reports based on Report Type 'HTML Email Status' do not show the emails that were sent.

When the trigger is deactivated or even amended to NOT do any update of the EmailMessage object, the EmailStatus records are created correctly and the Report works fine.

What's likely to be the underlying cause of the issue here? Could this be considered a 'bug' in salesforce.com's system?

Comment: Updating the trigger object in after phase is an anti-pattern and should be avoided if possible since it causes a subsequent DML in the same transaction against the originating records. This can cause all sorts of issues. Are you unable to do the updates in before phase?

Comment: I think the update has to be done in the 'after' phase (or later) because it uses certain field(s) that aren't yet populated in the 'before' phase.

Any idea what causes the 'EmailStatus' record to be missing?